# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined

Tags: amazon-ec2, meteor

I installed meteor version 1.0 on EC2 (Amazon Web Service) Centos. Created a simple application as: meteor create myapp. When accessing my app from web browser, I got the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined follower-livedata.js?74156c6baa89da861fc4ddb58ef158eac71e58e0:24
GET http://www.keenehuynh.com/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2  (index):24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined application-configuration.js?dcbf1f0774460fccf098a4c9e8fad4c3a0f2952f:24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined mongo.js?9bc2c5a8b2796fab86b51660ca643e5a49a30c84:29
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined autoupdate.js?c823646e93561d86e6bcb3cbd2457a8540e519c1:25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Autoupdate' of undefined meteor-platform.js?499a2f8522e25820b1153c69a92751ccaae507b3:23
GET http://www.keenehuynh.com/packages/jquery.js?265926494aaa3929cd2e30da265211c5929f37a4  (index):33
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined ui.js?5a663333fd30f8fd913f110e0ef779e84f67c4b8:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined templating.js?599ba307216da826d8b335332ebcc9a497a369a0:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined iron_dynamic-template.js?4d8240a576804301368600b388b97065770c2964:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Template' of undefined iron_layout.js?4e65c46acdaf0ce6a8b1a479d7b9d0b5c0902062:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined iron_location.js?0434907da386df80b0a769a8c4decc5374a3fdb6:25
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Template' of undefined iron_controller.js?c4a074a0f421ce052a59282e7eae64f7049061cb:26
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined iron_router.js?c45f7b94d616b48432e190827a3ca76d48e51e9d:24
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DDP' of undefined livedata.js?718526445deb4d9baacb6d92c551adea1d36c1e1:22
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Blaze' of undefined spacebars.js?3c496d2950151d744a8574297b46d2763a123bdf:23
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Router' of undefined global-imports.js?6fc397afa1f9e2f2f58bcff05db23cef9e32db68:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: Template is not defined template.keene.js?6853b3e161655dd7d01ba0a07237919f9a54ea67:2
Uncaught ReferenceError: Meteor is not defined keene.js?a4ef596255404350be2cc45303caea02f934cd17:1
```

Comment: you will need to show some code to help us help you, or did you not change anything about the default template app? how did you start meteor?

Comment: As it turned out, this is a nginx/meteor users mismatch and therefore permission issue. I installed nginx as root, and meteor as user my-user. To forward request to meteor app, in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf the required user is configured as my-user. When serving files nginx writes to temporary location /var/lib/nginx which is owned by user nginx and therefore user my-user has no permission to write. This causes GET failed for a few files (e.g. jquery.js, ddp.js, *.map, etc). I solved the problem by changing permission of /var/lib/nginx to give write-access to my-user.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nginx/meteor users mismatch and therefore permission issue. See my comment above.